# method for returning a new instance of a class

Tags: python

Using python 3.x, I would like to have a method of a class that returns an instance of the same class; it should be an inheritable method such that sub-classes of the class can call the function to return an instance of the sub-class, not the super-class.

What I would like to see is something like this

```py
class MyClass():
...
    def newInstance():##return a new instance of MyClass

class subClass(MyClass):##inherits newInstance from MyClass, but will return an instance of subClass
...
a = MyClass()
b = subClass()
c = a.newInstance()##a new instance of MyClass
d = b.newInstance()##a new instance of subClass
```

The following isn't inheritable in the right way

```py
class MyClass()
.
.
.
def newInstance(self)##return a new instance...
    out = MyClass()
    return out##a sub-class would return an instance of the superclass, not it's own class...
```

I tried this

```py
class MyClass()
.
.
.
def newInstance(self)##return a new instance...
    x = self.__class__ ##doesn't work, returns NoneType
    out = x()
    return out
```

which gives a TypeError 'NoneType' object is not callable.

I also tried

```py
def newInstance(self)##return a new instance...
    out = self.__init__()
    return out
```

which also returns a NoneType object.

Comment: `return type(self)()`?

Comment: jonrsharpe's solution (in Python 3, at least) should be equivalent to your `__class__` solution, and afaict both should work. Though I do find `type` cleaner.

Comment: so is `newInstance` an instance method on the class? Also, `__init__` shouldn't return anything, so `out = self.__init__()` would raise errors for NoneType anyways

Comment: Your second example (essentially `return self.__class__()` works fine for me and returns the subclassed type as you want. I'm not sure where you're getting NoneTypes error from.

Comment: As hinted to in Silvio Mayolo's comment, the version of Python could matter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Use the [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Creating a new A')

    @classmethod
    def newInstance(cls):
        return cls()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Creating a new B')

# Create new instances directly from the desired class    
a = A.newInstance()
b = B.newInstance()

# Create new instances from existing instances
a2 = a.newInstance()
b2 = b.newInstance()

print(type(a), type(b))
print(type(a2), type(b2))
```

This results in the following output:

```
Creating a new A
Creating a new B
Creating a new A
Creating a new B
<class '__main__.A'> <class '__main__.B'>
<class '__main__.A'> <class '__main__.B'>
```

Comment: Note that a class method can also invoked by an instance of a class, not just the class itself.

Comment: @chepner great point. I updated my answer to include that scenario.